# Number of components of a symmetric contravariant tensor

Tags: tensor-calculus

I am given the following question :

"What is the largest number of different components that a symmetric contravariant tensor of rank two can have when
(a) N = 4,
(b) N = 6?
What is the number for any value of N?"

where, I think, N is the number of dimensions in the space.

In a 3-dimensional space, a tensor of rank 2 has 9 (=3^2) components (for example, the stress tensor). This logic can be extended to see that in an N-dimensional space, a tensor of rank R can have N^R components. But here, in the given question, the 2nd rank contravariant tensor is 'symmetric'. How is this symmetricity going to affect the number of components?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the phrasing of the problem. Does "largest number of different components" stand for "number of independent components" - or "dimension of the tensor space"?

Comment: I think it is the number of independent components, our professor told us.

Comment: I see. So you may try to think in this way: given a symmetric $N\times N$ matrix, can you visualize a minimal set of entries which determine the matrix completely? How many are there?